# How do I write query from Spark to Redshift?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I connected via SSH to Dev Endpoint in Glue.
There is Spark 2.4.1 running.

I want to run a simple query `select * from pg_namespace;`

Also after that, want to move data from S3 to Redshift using COPY command.

How to write that in a Spark console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if you can use COPY command directly, and i haven't tried it.

For moving data from S3 to Redshift, you can use AWS Glue APIs.   [Please check here for sample codes from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-redshift.html)?  Behind the scenes, I think AWS Glue uses COPY / UNLOAD commands for moving data between S3 and REDSHIFT.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `aws cli` and `psql` from your ssh terminal.

For psql check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html

Then u can run `select` and `copy` command from it.

But I will not recommend as AWS Glue is serverless service so your cluster will be different everytime.

Comment: I did not downvote.. But also wondering - since my requirement is to run Glue job - what needs to be set in order from Glue to connect to RedShift (other than URL, user/pass)?

Comment: ohk . If it is glue job then check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-redshift.html